# Bootstrap Modal not popping up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm really new to bootstrap and I am trying to add a popup using Modals. I added the code and the scripts, but when you click on the button its not popping up. I can tell something is coming up because the background fades a little but a popup is not coming up. So I need a little bit of help figuring out why its not popping up.

```
My JavaScript links: 
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Code for Modals: 
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">

           <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Launch Modal</a>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap do you have? I've checked **2.3.2** [**click**](http://jsfiddle.net/7n07e895/1/),  and works fine. While it doesn't work on **3.2** - [**click**](http://jsfiddle.net/7n07e895/)

Comment: How can I get it to work with 3.2 @phillip100

Comment: [**there**](http://jsfiddle.net/7n07e895/3/) is a HTML sample which works.

Comment: Its popping up, but its not letting me click on anything to close it or exits the popup. Do you think that has something to do with where its being placed on the page? @phillip100

Comment: take look a at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a compatibility issue v2.X vs v3.X

**Bootstrap 3.0 New Classes & Elements**

> Modal markup has changed `.modal-header` `.modal-body` `.modal-footer` now get wrapped in `.modal-content` and `.modal-dialog`

**Modal Migration**

How to convert from a 2.x to 3.0 modal:

- remove `.hide` from the `.modal` (it's now hidden by default)
- wrap `.modal-header` `.modal-body` `.modal-footer` inside `.modal-content`
- wrap `.modal-content` inside `.modal-dialog`

Events are namespaced. For example to handle the modal `'show'` event, use `'show.bs.modal'`.

**[Reference](http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide)**

---

**Bootstrap 3 modal example**:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7n07e895/6/)

Comment: I'm lost now, I took the same code that you gave me from that link. It is popping up, but I cant click on it to close

Comment: updated answer with a modal example. You should have a `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute in close buttons

Comment: I do, I was asking do you think it has something to do with where its being placed on the page because it wont even let me click anywhere inside

Comment: Yes it could be. Try to place it right after you open `body` tag. The opening modal button can be anywhere

Comment: One more question, do you know how to fade the background when the button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, add `fade` class to the modal ( `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal"> ...` )

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do for modals with just JavaScript and Bootstrap is to have an onClick event on the button that executes a JavaScript method that displays the modal.

In your HTML:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show') 
    }
</script>
```

Just change the function name `myFunction` to the name you want and `myModal` to the id of your modal.

Here is the bootstrap docs, where the modal stuff is located, for future reference [getbootstrap.com/javascript/](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Comment: Its popping up, but now its not allowing me to close it or click anywhere inside the popup.

Answer (score 0):

**Complete Example using CDN. SO that you can download the latest version from Url**

```
<html>
    <head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css">


<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <body>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```